# New AAP to google play store shows the Your Android App Bundle uses an upload key that is too weak

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-keystore, android-security, android-app-signing

New AAP to google play store shows the Your Android App Bundle uses an upload key that is too weak.

I am using an existing keystore file which is already used in our other apps. This key is using for a very long years.

With the same key we have running more than 10 apps in the google play store.

So I have used the same key here as well but it shows the above error.
[image]

Comment: Probably you need to update your key and used a more secure one. Unfortunately ,we can't be of help here as it's related to google play policies, you need to contact google customer service for this.

Comment: If I update the key, does it affect the already available google play store apps?

Comment: If it's a update over the app,  it will affect the previous one, as both apps won't be signed using same keys. If it's completely a new app it shouldn't affect others

Comment: I am using white labelled apps. So how it will be added? I can't able to use different key for different apps/

Comment: @Nitish this is incorrect: in most cases, the key the AAB is signed with is independent to the key the APKs (that devices install) is signed with. The error message suggests this is a new app anyway.

Comment: @Pierre Are you mentioning i need to create a new key for the upcoming apps?

Comment: You don't have to, but it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The key used to sign the Android App Bundle is only used for Google Play to recognize you and ensure the artifact you upload hasn't been tampered with between you signing it and Google Play servers receiving it.

This key (also called "upload key"), in particular, is different to the one that will be used to sign the APKs that will be served to your users. The default option when you create a new app is Google Play will generate the APK signing key for you, so it will be different from your other apps (unless you've explicitly requested to be the same as another app when first releasing your AAB).

It is recommended that you use a different key for each of your apps so that if one if compromised, the damage is limited and the recovery easier (only one key to change), but it isn't enforced by Google Play.

Comment: We are using the white-labelled (multiple apps with same code) apps with the same Keystore. Already all the apps are using the same key and are available in the google play store. Can you suggest how we should proceed with the new app (white labelled) push?

Comment: I'd recommend a different signing key. The upload key can be the same since it can be reset if needed.